# Sum of values from facts

Tags: prolog

I am trying to add different values together, let's say I have this:

`%person(Name, Points).
person(piotr, 3).
person(daniel, 4).
person(marlena, 4).
person(grzegorz, 1).
person(ania, 2).
person(robert, 4).
person(gabrysia, 5).
person(julia, 6).
person(agata, 7).
person(bartek, 4).`

I also have a list of names :

`[daniel, marlena, grzegorz]`

And the problem is I'm trying to add these people(from list) points together and I don't know how. 
I used many ways but none worked.

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this but one of the most straight forward is to think of two cases:

```
% what is the sum when you have an empty list
sum_vals([],0).

% what is the sum when you know one value and the sum of the rest 
sum_vals([N|Names],Sum) :-
    person(N,Val),
    sum_vals(Names,Sum1),
    Sum is Sum1 + Val.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `aggregate` library:

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate)).

sum_persons(Ns, R) :-
    aggregate(sum(P), N, (member(N, Ns), person(N, P)), R).
```